# 2006 iMac will not respond to standard command to restore or anything

Tags: imac, restore, macos

I have a 2006 iMac and a backup and would like to restore the to the original install. However, it can't be upgraded, its too old, so finding software is impossible.

Tried the Mac OS X Tiger system disk, which is the oldest I have, but its too new!

Tried setting NVRAM, no response.  *Command+R*, no response.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: You say the Tiger disc is "too new". What happens when you try to use the disc? Do you get nothing on screen? Do you get an error?

Comment: Please note that Tiger is NOT too new for that computer. The newest OS that that computer can handle is Snow Leopard (10.6.8). Tiger is 10.4.

Comment: Try inserting the Tiger disc. When you start the computer, hold down the "C" key until you see an image on the screen